# Does filling in cement(inside or outside the house) act as a deterrent to the soil-water and mold problems resulting from it?

Tags: drain, mold, french-drain

An experienced contractor suggested to me that filling cement near the bottom one foot of basement walls will stop the water from coming inside the basement. And also, a 2 feet of cement floor around the perimeter of house will help deter the water, as well. Is this a proven technique?

Comment: What are the walls and floor currently made of?

Comment: We need photos. In general, hardscaping is just a way to funnel water away. The catch with concrete is that it cracks, and the cracks often become major entry points for water. You're likely better off using graded soil.

Comment: If you're talking basically something like a walkway all around the perimeter of the house then yes it can help especially if you have something like an old stone foundation. Soil type, drainage, weather and other considerations need to be considered. It shouldn't be the first solution you consider but if doing things like grading, extending downspouts, keeping gutters clean, etc haven't fixed the issue it can work in some situations. Ideally though you'd want to dig around your entire foundation and properly waterproof the walls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concrete is porous and will not completely stop water from entering anything. If you want to stop water from entering your basement you need to have your exterior soil properly graded and packed, in addition to your gutters cleaned and draining away several feet away from your house. Regarding grading, a good number to shoot for is 1" of 'fall' for every horizontal foot.

Beyond that there are multiple solutions, the best being re-waterproofing the exterior of your basement, but that's expensive and most people go for an interior draining system, such as one involving a sump pump. In anycase, you will want to start with external factors such as gutters and grading. That should address the majority of your basement water issues.

Comment: Concrete is indeed porous but it is significantly less porous than soil.